# Showing that the set $\displaystyle \{e^{2\pi i (mx+ny)}\}_{n,m=-\infty}^\infty$ is an orthonormal set

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, inner-products

I have the following problem:

> Show that the set $\displaystyle \{e^{2\pi i (mx+ny)}\}_{n,m=-\infty}^\infty$ is an
>   orthonormal set in $L^2(D)$, where $D$ is any square whose sides have
>   length one and are parallel to the coordinate axes.

This problem is little confusing to me, because so far I have been doing similar problems, where there has been only one index letter, namely $n$ (for example $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$).

I think that I'm supposed to do the following:

A) Showing that:

$$\int_{k-1}^k\int_{k-1}^ke^{2\pi i(mx+ny)}\overline{e^{2\pi i(ax+by)}}\;dx\:dy = 1,$$

when $m=a$ and $n=b$ and $0$ otherwise. Have I understood this problem correctly? Any guides/hints?

Thnx for any help! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: if you prove that that integral is $1$ for $a=m$ and $b=n$, and $0$ otherwise, you prove that the set is orthonormal.

To prove that, note that
$$\overline{e^{2\pi i(mx+ny)}}=e^{-2\pi i(mx+ny)}$$

If $a=m$, $b=n$, the product in the integral is $1$, since is the product of a complex number whose mudulus is $1$ and its conjugate.

If not, the product is $e^{2\pi i(cx+dy)}$ for some integers $c,d$, not both zero. You can split the integral:
$$\int_0^1e^{2\pi icx}dx\int_0^1e^{2\pi idy}dy$$

Assume, for example, that $c\neq 0$. Then
$$\int_0^1e^{2\pi icx}dx=\frac1{2\pi i c}(\exp(2\pi ic)-\exp(0))=0$$
so the pruduct is $0$.

Same reasoning if $d\neq0$.